# Windows phone emulator is doing a complete OS boot

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-7.1

Recently I installed windows phone SDK 7.1. I built a small project using VS 2010 Express Edition and tried to run my first app, but my emulator loads and displays "Windows phone emulator is doing a complete OS boot" and then automatically get closed. And finally i get a error "The interface is unknown".

I am on Windows 7 laptop with 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: I don't know.. just downloaded what I found. Is 1 GB RAM a issue?

Comment: Possibly. The system requirements on the download page states `3gb` http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570 Also, is your graphics card driver model `WDDM 1.1`? I believe 1.0 and below isn't supported. (You can find by starting `dxdiag`, then select the `display` tab. On the right hand side, there's a label called `Driver Model`.

Comment: My driver model is listed as "WDDM 1.1" there.

Comment: Try uninstalling it and installing the non-beta version. If not, maybe the lack of RAM is causing the problem. Here's more info on the system requirements for the emulator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: Okay thanks.. but I think I have to drop my idea on developing windows phone app. Will try on some other computer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue. I tried uninstalling the sdk and re-installed it once again. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you if you have dual graphics hardware like I have on my laptop. Change graphics settings to default to use integrated graphics. Once I did this the emulator started working. I'd tried all kinds of things before this, i.e., uninstalling, reinstalling, repairing etc., and none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue, both in VMware in Virtualbox. I've NEVER reinstalled anything, havent' painted walls because my bread dropped on the ground greased side down.

I just read the docs again and gave my machine (real or virtual) at least 4GB of RAM.

For WP7, WDDM version (1.0/1.1) doesn't pose an issue to start the simulator.